Why does the variation of an integral introduce another variable?
I am confused about the following step:

$$E = \int_0^T \left( \int_0^\infty s(t - \tau)K(\tau) \text{ d}\tau - r(t) \right)^2 \text{ dt}$$
If we allow for $K \to K + \delta K$ we see that $E \to E + \delta E$ where
$$\delta E = 2 \int_0^T \text dt \int_0^\infty \text d \tilde \tau \left( \int_0^\infty s(t - \tau)K(\tau) \text{ d}\tau - r(t) \right) s(t - \tilde \tau) \delta K(\tilde \tau)$$

Where does the integral  over $\text d \tilde \tau$ come from? I get that the term $s(t - \tilde \tau) \delta K(\tilde \tau)$ results from the chain rule but why do we introduce another variable for it?

It looks like they're using $$\left(\int_0^\infty s(t-\tau)K(\tau),d\tau - r(t)\right)^2 = \left(\int_0^\infty s(t-\tau)K(\tau),d\tau - r(t)\right)\left(\int_0^\infty s(t-\tilde\tau)K(\tilde\tau),d\tilde\tau - r(t)\right)$$ and if this is the case, we introduce another variable $\tilde\tau$ so that we can bring one integral into the other.

@BrianMoehring Thanks for your comment :) Is it somehow necessary to define the square in terms of two integrals with different differentials? Could there be a problem if we used $\text d \tau$ in both?

For the equality I showed, there's no problem with using the same variable.  The problem comes in the next step, Essentially $$(\int f(x) dx)(\int f(y) dy) = \int (\int f(x) dx) f(y) dy = \int (\int f(x)f(y) dx) dy$$ is fine while $$(\int f(x) dx)(\int f(x) dx) = \int (\int f(x) dx) f(x) dx = \int (\int f(x) f(x) dx) dx$$ is notational nonsense.

@BrianMoehring And in order for the chain rule term to make sense outside of the parentheses we need to introduce another integral regardless. Kinda makes sense but feels a little shaky.

Just need to expand the following equation
[\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}s(t-\tau)K(\tau)d\tau-r(t)+\int_{0}^{\infty}s(t-\tilde{\tau})K(\tilde{\tau})d\tilde{\tau}\right)^2]

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
